# What's the difference between `*` operator and `deref()` method?

Tags: rust, dereference

What I've been told is that once an object (in this cast `sth`) implements the `Drop` trait then it can use `*` operator to call its `deref()` method. So I think the result of using `*` should be the same as the result of explicitly call `deref()`. But I find in some cases the two results are not equal. For example:

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;

fn main() {
    let sth = Box::new(5);
    println!("{:p}", sth.deref());
    println!{"{:?}", *sth};
}
```

I searched the docs and know that the signature of `deref()` of `Box` is `(&self)->&T`. That means it should return a reference of inner value. However, `*sth` looks like it is returning the inner value directly. Why are the two results not equal?

Answer (score 4):

`*` is not the same as `v.deref()` (or more exactly `Deref::deref(&v)`) - it's more like `*Deref::deref(&v)` (note the `*`).

Regarding `Box` specifically, it can move out of it, like:

```rust
let s = Box::new(String::new());
let moved_out = *s;
// s; // Error, moved out of the `Box`.
```

In either type, it creates a place - it can be `*Deref::deref(&v)` or `*DerefMut::deref_mut(&v)`, depending on whether mutable access is required.

Answer (score 0):

As Chayim answered `deref()` is used to get a reference to the inner item, which the `*` then actually accesses.

However when it comes to `Box` you won't find its behaviour regulated by any trait (at least as yet): [`Box` is a  language item](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/lang-items.html).

While unlike references it *looks* like a normal type it really has the same status, and leaves at the core of the language itself. As a result, it can (and does) behave in ways no other type can.

One of these behaviours is the ability to move on dereference, which is completely unique to it (RFCs have been proposed for that in the past but AFAIK little progress has been made).

Although in your specific case that's not even involved: `println!` will always reference its parameters, so

```rust
    println!{"{:?}", *sth};
```

really does

```rust
    let args = Args::new(&*sth);
```

and then you get the value because there is a blanket `impl Display for &T where T: Display` which delegates to `T`'s implementation (and the same for `Box` incidentally).

Which you can check by duplicating the line and seeing that it works fine, which it would not have if the value had been moved (and the box dropped).